# Julia: How to define correctly a function that uses types that depend on numbers?

Tags: arrays, julia

I use arrays but I do not need to change the length at any point, but at the same time I do not know their length while I am writing the code. I know the length only when I need to create them.

In particular I am using StaticArrays and I want to define a function of the type `f(v::MVector{N,Float64})` that will accept as input an `MVector` of any length. How do I type this in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a running example, suppose we have a vector `mv` which is fixed length, but we know its length only at run-time. It could be defined like so:

```
julia> using StaticArrays

julia> mv = @MVector rand(4)
4-element MVector{4,Float64}:
 0.978253
 0.691035
 0.988942
 0.770601
```

To define a function which operates on this vector, we could write:

```
julia> mysum(v::MVector{N,Float64}) where {N} = sum(v)
```

Note the `where {N}` notation which makes it address all fixed sizes.

But this is unnecessary. Writing:

```
julia> mysum2(v) = sum(v)
```

works to optimize for the specific length, even at run-time, since a new version of the function is compiled for each type of the parameter. This is because Julia specializes a function according to parameter types. MVectors include the length in their type, and so a specialized function for this length is generated at run-time and used.

Comment: Thanks! I find it hard to find what I need in the documentation, even though it is generally well written. I guess it is a problem of proper indexing